# How to have dynamic code splitting with babel and webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I am trying to get dynamic code splitting using webpack 4 and babel 6 through babel-loader and it's kind of impossible. Look at this code:

```
import Chunk1 from './chunks/Chunk1'
import('./chunks/Chunk2')
    .then( module => {
        Chunk2('Asynch')
    })
;

Chunk1('Sync')
```

Webpack split it in 2 chunks if I don't use babel-loader, but when babel-loader get into the mix the bundle splitting is over. This is the way I add babel-loader to the webpack configuration:

```
{
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'chunkTest.js')
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(appDirectory, 'chunkTest.js'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, 'chunks')
      ],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          // No options at all
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

I've been trying for days with no luck, any help is much appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your Babel config file?

Comment: If you don't have a Babel config file, you need to specify the Babel preset inside `options` with something like `presets: ['@babel/preset-env']`.

Comment: You need to add `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` to your babel config, so that babel knows how to parse dynamic imports, but lets Webpack do its work.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working yet. Tried installing and adding to the options `plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']`  `presets: ['env']` `presets: [ ['env', {modules: false}] ]` and combinations of them but no luck :(